# Symfony cache issue after upgraded to symfony from 2.8 to 3.4

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Recently I have migrated from symfony 2.8 to 3.4 and the application is breaking. If I load any routes by default the login page loads and if I hit the route from 2nd time onwards I am getting this error message.

Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry

[image]

If I delete cache folder it seems working initially and 2nd time onwards while hitting any routes I am getting this issue.

Comment: There are some older questions on this.  At some point `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry` was moved to a different namespace `Doctrine\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry` so your dependency versions are probably not correct.  Search for some of the basically identical questions and see which apply to your case.

Comment: If I remember right, the cache directory changed from `app/cache` to `var/cache` from 2.8 to 3.4. I would suggest you verify if the `app/cache` folder exists and delete it manually if it does.